# Does Python's IDLE editor use a fallback font?

Tags: python, fonts, python-idle

I am trying to find a font that supports a series of special characters which IDLE seems to have. The configure IDLE menu seems to claim that it's using Courier New. However when I check the contents of Courier New, it doesn't support the characters that IDLE is somehow showing. Does IDLE use a modified verision of Courier New or does it use a fallback font of some kind?

These are the characters that IDLE is showing some of which aren't in Courier New: (e.g. )

```
[("⌐■","■"),("°","°"),("⇀","↼"),("´•","•`"),("´","`"),("`","´"),("ó","ò"),("ò","ó"),("⸌","⸍"),("Ƹ̵̡","Ʒ"),("ᗒ","ᗕ"),("⟃","⟄"),("⪧","⪦"),
("⪦","⪧"),("⪩","⪨"),("⪨","⪩"),("⪰","⪯"),("⫑","⫒"),("⨴","⨵"),("⩿","⪀"),("⩾","⩽"),("⩺","⩹"),("⩹","⩺"),("◥▶","◀◤"),("◍","◎"),("⌣","⌣”"),
("͡⎚","⎚"),("≋","≋"),("૦ઁ","૦ઁ"),("ꗞ","ꗞ"),("ꔸ","ꔸ"),("꘠","꘠"),("ꖘ","ꖘ"),("܍","܍"),("ළ","ළ"),("◉","◉"),("☉","☉"),("・","・"),
("▰","▰"),("ᵔ","ᵔ"),("ﾟ","ﾟ"),("□","□"),("☼","☼"),("*","*"),("`","`"),("⚆","⚆"),("⊜","⊜"),("&gt;","&gt;"),("❍","❍"),("￣","￣"),        
("─","─"),("✿","✿"),("•","•"),("T","T"),("^","^"),("ⱺ","ⱺ"),("@","@"),("ȍ","ȍ"),("x","x"),("-","-"),("$","$"),("Ȍ","Ȍ"),("ʘ","ʘ"),
("Ꝋ","Ꝋ"),("",""),("",""),("⸟","⸟"),("๏","๏"),("ⴲ","ⴲ"),("■","■"),("ﾟﾟ"),("◕","◕"),("◔","◔"),("✧","✧"),("■","■"),("♥","♥"),
("¬","¬"),("⨶","⨶"),("⨱","⨱"),("⏓","⏓"),("⏒","⏒"),("⍜","⍜"),("⍤","⍤"),("ᚖ","ᚖ"),("ᴗ","ᴗ"),("ಠ","ಠ"),("σ","σ"),("☯","☯"),("の","の"),("￢￢"),("э","э")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question has two subquestions.

1. How are the pixel patterns for characters generated and what part does IDLE have?  The short answer is that IDLE has nothing to do with generating them. IDLE uses tkinter, Python's interface to the tcl/tk GUI framework.  IDLE calls tkinter.font.families to get the list of font names recognized on your system.  That methods calls tk, which calls your OS.

I believe that the pixel pattern displayed for a particular Unicode codepoint ultimately depends on the font subsystem for your OS, perhaps modified by parameters set by tk.  The type of font (TrueFont or other) likely affects the outcome also.

2. How can one tell what characters are actually available for a particular font on a particular system?  As you discovered, the OS may fill in some blanks, so you may get many more than you expected.  I presume by "check the contents" you meant looking up the supported characters in some external reference.

Right now, on IDLE, the dialog's font test display is limited to a subset of ASCII.  To test anything else, one must pre-generate a test selection in an editor and hit 'Apply', or exit and test either by keyboard entry or printing a string that uses unicode escapes.  I hope to someday improve this by augmenting the current dynamically generated display of test characters in the dialog itself.

EDIT: I have since read a tcl unicode doc that explains that tk tries to display each text char in widgets with the widget font but if it cannot, tk tries to find a best-match font that will display the char.  Since the search is not guaranteed to succeed even when it 'should', it is best to specify a font that has most of the chars one plans to use.